How to get error on my object instead of its properties in Zod
I have a schema for an object like to:
const formValidationSchema = z.object({
  ...otherFields
  user: z.object({
    id: z.number({ required_error: "Choose a user" })
    type: z.object({
      id: z.number()
    }, { required_error: "Choose type of user" })
  })
})

This is the object I am filling out in my form:
type Form = {
  ...otherFields
  user: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    type: {
      id: string
    }
  }
}

For referance I am using Mantines useForm-hook to manage my form-state.
In my form i have two inputs:
<UserSelect value={form.user} onChange={(value) => form.setFieldValue("user", value)} error={form.errors["user.id"]}/>
<UserTypeSelect value={form.user.type} onChange={(value) => form.setFieldValue("user.type", value} error={form.errors["user.type"]} />

When I try to submit without values I get the error messages correctly. But when I fill in my user-input the user.id error message doesn't go away. I think that is because that field isnt validated a new since im never directly setting that field.

So to my question. Is it possible to get an error message on an object if it is missing certain values? E.g my errors look like this now:
{
  "user.id": "Choose a user",
  "user.type": "Choose type of user",
}

Can I do anything to the zod-schema to make it look like this:
{
  "user": "Choose a user",
  "user.type": "Choose type of user",
}

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nostalgic-julien-c26wtm
Click submit, then choose a user. The error doesnt go away :(

I'm very glad to see the issue broken down, but may you add a [mcve] showing the issue?

I can try to create one

Made a sandbox that you can use
